# apache poi で pptx の加工をしたいのですが、サンプルがどこかに無いでしょうか？

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

apache poi を利用して pptx の加工を行う処理を作っています。
具体的には

テキスト置換
画像挿入
グラフ挿入

行いたいです。
ぐぐってみると
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873725/how-to-get-pptx-slide-notes-text-using-apache-poi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471472/does-anyone-have-an-example-of-apache-poi-converting-pptx-to-png

この辺りでテキスト置換、画像挿入はできそうだなと感じたのですが、グラフ挿入が見つかりません。

ご経験のあるかたにご相談させて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

チャートの新規作成は[XSLFChartに引数なしのコンストラクターが無い](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFChart.html)のでOpenXMLデータや`PackagePart`を生成するなどしないと無理ではないかと思います。ですので通常は[あらかじめチャートを配置したpptxを更新する](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/PieChartDemo.java)形を取ります。

Comment: テンプレートを使う形ならできそうなんですね！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

実際に自分で試したわけではないので情報だけですが[Aspose Java for Apache POI](https://asposeapachepoi.codeplex.com)というのがあるようです。これを使えばグラフ挿入出来ませんかね？参考資料は以下です。

- [Aspose.Slides - Create PPT Charts](https://asposeapachepoi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20PPT%20Charts&referringTitle=Missing%20Features%20of%20Apache%20POI%20SL)
- [Working with Charts - Aspose.Slides for Java - Documentation -

  Aspose.com](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesjava/Working+with+Charts)

Comment: なるほど！ちょこちょこ触ってみますね！